# imagemagick convert does not produce alpha gradient for specific image

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I'm using convert to generate images with a fade gradient, converting images like this:

---

[image: cropped image]

---

to images like this (note the fade at the bottom):

---

[image: cropped and faded image]

---

The source images (e.g., first image above) are PNGs converted from PDFs (if that helps at all). The convert command I use is:

```
convert source.png -alpha set -background none -channel A \
   -sparse-color barycentric "0,%[h] none 0,{img_height*(1-fade_height)} white" \
   +channel source_fade.png
```

where `{img_height*(1-fade_height)}` is replaced by the image's height times a factor that determines where I want the fade to start (e.g. for a 1000px height image, maybe 800).

There is one image for which this does not seem to work:

---

[image: Cropped image that does not seem to like to be faded]

---

Running the corresponding command on this image results in just a blank image with something vaguely gradient-looking at the bottom:

```
convert img/covers/Venn_1888_cover_cropped.png \
  -alpha set -background none -channel A \
  -sparse-color barycentric "0,%[h] none 0,778 white" \
  +channel img/covers/Venn_1888_cover_cropped_fade.png
```

---

[image: incorrect, blank image with something vaguely gradient-looking at the bottom]

---

Why might this be happening? If it helps, I'm on MacOS 13.4.1 (22F82), with homebrew imagemagick:

```
# convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-11 Q16-HDRI aarch64 21206 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (4.2)
```

Comment: Try `magick YOURIMAGE -separate +smush 10 result.jpg` to see all channels side-by-side. I guess the info is in the alpha channel.

Comment: Works for me in IM 6, but not IM 7. Not sure why at the moment. This image is grayscale and has no alpha channel to start. The other images are rgba (with alpha channel to start).  So that may have something to do with it. I don't have time now to look into it further, but will try later today.  If I add -colorspace sRGB after reading the input, then this latter image seems to work.

Comment: That's it! If I add -colorspace sRGB to the command it works. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I have posted a bug report on the IM GIT forum. This does not look like behavior that I would expect.

Comment: The report I got back is that it is a bug and is being fixed for the next release. Use -colorspace sRGB for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution, but I am not sure if this is a bug in Imagemagick 7.

Your good result comes from an SRGB image with an alpha channel.  Your bad result comes from a Grayscale image with no alpha channel.

The solution is to convert the bad image to SRGB via -colorspace sRGB after reading it. That is

```
convert img/covers/Venn_1888_cover_cropped.png \
  -colorspace sRGB -alpha set -background none -channel A \
  -sparse-color barycentric "0,%[h] none 0,778 white" \
  +channel img/covers/Venn_1888_cover_cropped_fade.png
```